# Ubuntu 20.04 very slow, sometime hanging

Tags: 20.04

Recently, I install Ubuntu in my computer. My configuration is the following:

- Intel® Core™ i7-10700 CPU @ 2.90GHz × 16
- Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (CML GT2)
- SSD: 500
- RAM: 16GB

But my computer seems very slow when I open Activities, or run a Java process in InteliJ, or Java in Android, or when I run yarn start or something else. I don't know why. My computer sometime hangs. I captured some screenshots of my process.

Please help me resolve the problem, or help me speed up my computer. I think about reinstall Hackintosh, because I am more familiar with MacOS than Ubuntu.

Some images that might be useful:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

[image: Image 4]

[image: Image 5]

[image: Image 6]

Comment: System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab` to create some. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

Comment: Thanks @waltinator. default my swap 2GB, but I'm check only  free 100MB, you mean I must increase swap RAM to 16GB or more

Comment: No, you don't increase swap to 16G. Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`. Also show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model # of your computer or motherboard. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Also show me `top`.

Comment: @heynnema. If you see screenshot above.

Comment: @heynnema: - grep -i swap /etc/fstab: 0, bios version: 1401. My Bios: Asus EX-B460M-V5.

Comment: That's not the `top` command. This is Ubuntu, correct?

Comment: @heynnema. Yes, this is Ubuntu. I screenshots system monitor, it's same top command.

Comment: Show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab`... but EDIT that output into your question please. Give me the "regular" `top` command.

Comment: Also show me `sudo lshw -C memory`.

Comment: @heynnema. I edit my question. Please review it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BIOS**

Asus EX-B460M-V5

You have BIOS 1401. There's a newer BIOS available, version 1604, dated 3/16/21, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/CSM/EX-B460M-V5/HelpDesk_BIOS/).

**RAM**

You may need more RAM. Add another one of these...

[image]

**SWAP**

We'll increase your 2G /swapfile to 4G, and revisit the performance metrics.

[image]

We'll currently leave your vm.swappiness at 60.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Comment: RAM: I think 16GB enough for my need. SWAP: ok I try, and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

What increased my performance slightly on various setups is turning off the "animations" in Tweaks. Worth trying.
[image]

Also looking at your Swap I'd definitely increase it. (to about the size of your RAM at least) Even though it may not be related to your current issue your swap is awfully low and may cause other issues later on. (source: https://itsfoss.com/swap-size/)

[image]

### To increase swap:

`sudo swapoff -a`

Resize

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=8`

Permissions

`sudo chmod 600 /swapfile`

Make usable

```
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

Edit /etc/fstab and add the new swapfile if it isn’t already there (based on suggestion from @heynnema )

`/swapfile none swap sw 0 0`

Check the amount of swap available

`grep SwapTotal /proc/meminfo`

Comment: No, you don't increase swap to *"about the size of your RAM at least"*. And you assumed a /swapfile, and didn't delete the original one. What if they have a swap partition? And you forgot to check/add the /swapfile line in /etc/fstab.

Comment: You don't need to delete anything when changing size instead of creating a new swapfile from scratch. (https://bogdancornianu.com/change-swap-size-in-ubuntu/) Also the "about the size of your RAM at least" is the most widely shared recommendation as far as I have seen (at least). I mean, given you have the necessary disk space there's only drawbacks in having swap smaller than RAM. Especially if you hibernate. (https://itsfoss.com/swap-size/)

Comment: Yes, I assumed the swap file because because "starting with Ubuntu 17.04, the swap partition was replaced by a swap file. The main advantage of the swap file is easy resizing" (source: https://linuxbsdos.com/2017/04/18/swap-partition-out-swap-file-in-on-ubuntu-17-04/). Assuming a user is using the current and up to date setup is not necessarily wrong. (especially since the OP is running 20.04)

Comment: I've added the `/swapfile none swap sw 0 0` line based on your suggestion

Comment: The added swap size table is nice, but I don't believe the info is current, esp for Ubuntu 20.04. Any /swapfile 3G or less, is too small. And their hibernation numbers are just their RAM + swap. Funny enough, the table matches the 4G swap for 16G RAM that I recommended in my accepted answer.

Comment: I guess we'll disagree then. :)

Comment: Fair enough. AU is a good place for this kind of dialog, like we had. It's also a good place for new contributors to learn from more senior contributors :-)